# How to get youtube suggestions videos via api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I noticed in youtube page. for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=related&hl=en&v=Xr8vUTm64h0  on the right part of the page, there have a `suggestions` list.

I would like to ask: how to get this `suggestions` list via api if I have the current video's all the information? is it relay on a category search or use other search method? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably wanting the [related videos feed.](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Related_videos_feed)

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Xr8vUTm64h0/related?v=2&fields=entry(id)
```

[JSON formatted example.](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Xr8vUTm64h0/related?v=2&fields=entry%28id%29&alt=json)

Comment: This endpoint does not exist anymore